# How can I get Key press in MFC App when the app is inactive

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, keyboard, hotkeys

I create an app using MFC Framework that auto hide on startup, and if I press SHIFT+W then it shows the Windows.

I inherited the function PreTranslateMessage() like that:

```
BOOL CTestAppDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg){
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN){
        if (pMsg->wParam == 0x57){
            if (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000) {
                ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
            }   
        }
    }

    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

But this function only catches the keypresses if MFC App is active. So if this App is hide in OnPaint() function with ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) then it cannot catch the SHIFT+W to show windows normally. How can I do for it? Thank all

Comment: Don’t call ShowWindow() from OnPaint().

Comment: Shift+W is a poor chose of hotkey, because that would mean that any time somebody wanted to type a capital W, your app would show itself.

Answer (score 1):

As explained under [Keyboard Focus and Activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keyboard-focus-and-activation):

> The system posts keyboard messages to the message queue of the foreground thread that created the window with the keyboard focus.

As a window gets hidden the system transfers keyboard focus to the next eligible window, causing your window to no longer receive keyboard input as you observed.

There are several ways to observe input globally. In this case the most appropriate solution is to just call [`RegisterHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey) and provide a [`CWnd::OnHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onhotkey) implementation for the respective receiver of the [`WM_HOTKEY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-hotkey) message.